# Outlook - distribution list member details

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to get details for users in a distribution list (containing ~200 people).

When I create a new email, add this DL as the only recipient and run the macro below, it returns ~15 first results, then "Outlook is trying to retrieve data from the Microsoft Exchange server" tray message appears and after some time I get "The operation failed" error.

If I continue the code execution the next ~15 values are returned and this issue reappears. Seams like there is some Exchange anti-spam limit.

```
Sub GetDetails(olMail As MailItem)

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To olMail.Recipients.Count ' count = 1
        If olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Is Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.Members.Count ' count ~= 200
                Debug.Print olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.Members.Item(j).GetExchangeUser.FirstName
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But if I expand the distribution list (using the '+' icon) and run slightly modified code, results for all users are returned with no issues (taking a few seconds only).

```
Sub GetDetails(olMail As MailItem)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To olMail.Recipients.Count ' count ~= 200
        If Not olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is there anyone on the distro list that isn't an ExchangeUser? Your second snippet accounts for that, but it looks like the first one does not (it handles the `Recipients.Item(1)` but *not* the individual recipients'). (this is just a shot in the dark, and I don't have any other ideas)

Comment: All are exchange users. The problem is I don't know how to iterate through them as through individual recipients.

Comment: one thought would be to add a call to the WinAPI Sleep function for 100 or 200 ms. the error you're getting looks like a conflict/timeout sort of thing that you might avoid with a very small pause at each iteration.

Comment: Tried even with 1 - 1.5s. Issue still occurs. "Expanded" list (2nd approach) returns data for all emails in ~3 seconds..

Comment: Also it doesn't seem to be related to the `GetExchangeUser` method. Changing it to anything else (e.g. `Class`) doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Seems like the first approach queries the Exchange Server while the second queries all the data locally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to release Outlook COM objects instantly in the code. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. When you are done, just set a variable to Nothing to release the reference to the object.

Comment: Issue occurs after few iterations (~10). Releasing objects                 
`Dim o
Set o = olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.Members.Item(j)
Debug.Print o.GetExchangeUser.FirstName
Set o = Nothing`
doesn't help.

Comment: I see a lot of dots in the single line of code. So, I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and methods calls and declare them on separate line (each property or method on a single line of code). Thus you will be able to release them in a timely manner.

Comment: I agree but that doesn't resolve the issue. It seems that the `AddressEntry` is resolved locally and `AddressEntry.Members` on the server hitting some limits for big DLs.

Comment: Even this code causes the issue: `For j = 1 To 20
Set m = olMail.Recipients.Item(i).AddressEntry.Members
Set m = Nothing
Next j`

Comment: I still see a lot of dots in the single line of code. Try to avoid them.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Updated (working) code based on Eugene's feedback:

```
Sub GetDetails(olMail As MailItem)
    Dim oRecipients As Recipients
    Dim oRecipient As Recipient
    Dim oMembers As AddressEntries
    Dim oMember As AddressEntry
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, dRecCnt As Integer, dMemCnt As Integer

    Set oRecipients = olMail.Recipients

    dRecCnt = oRecipients.Count
    For i = 1 To dRecCnt
        Set oRecipient = oRecipients.Item(i)

        If oRecipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser Is Nothing Then
            Set oMembers = oRecipient.AddressEntry.Members

            dMemCnt = oMembers.Count
            For j = 1 To dMemCnt
                Set oMember = oMembers.Item(j)

                Debug.Print c & ": " & oMember.GetExchangeUser.FirstName

                Set oMember = Nothing
            Next j

            Set oMembers = Nothing
        End If

        Set oRecipient = Nothing
    Next i

    Set oRecipients = Nothing
End Sub
```