# Query user's Outlook properties to see if they are a member of a specific distribution group in Outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I wish to query a user's Outlook properties via Excel to see if they are a member of a specific distribution list.

We have four teams and also visitors known as Other.

The aim is to query if a user is a member of *Team A Operators* if so return a string value of Team A, elseif member of *Team B operators* return a string value of Team B and so on up to Team D. If not a member of any of those then return a string value of Other.

Also what is the user identifier for Outlook? Is it their email address or their login identification?

Comment: If you know the lists then rather than from user to list you could try from list to user. [How to access contact groups in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049419/how-to-access-contact-groups-in-excel-vba) may be useful even if only for demonstrating how to reference Outlook from Excel.  [Outlook - distribution list member details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43418692/outlook-distribution-list-member-details) demonstrates returning list member information so you may compare names of a list in a mailitem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetMemeber` method of the `DistLisItem` class from the Outlook object model to get each member of the distribution list. For example, the following code locates every distribution list in the default `Contacts` folder and determines whether the list contains the current user:

```
Sub DisplayYourDLNames() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myDistList As Outlook.DistListItem
 Dim myFolderItems As Outlook.Items 
 Dim x As Integer 
 Dim y As Integer 
 Dim iCount As Integer 
 
 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
 Set myFolderItems = myFolder.Items 
 iCount = myFolderItems.Count 
 For x = 1 To iCount 
   If TypeName(myFolderItems.Item(x)) = "DistListItem" Then 
     Set myDistList = myFolderItems.Item(x) 
     For y = 1 To myDistList.MemberCount 
       If myDistList.GetMember(y).Name = myNameSpace.CurrentUser.Name Then
         MsgBox "Your are a member of " & myDistList.DLName 
       End If 
     Next y 
   End If 
 Next x 

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi yeah i have seen that online however i need to check a specified person within the directory and see if they are on a specific distribution list not me.

Comment: Use the `GetMember` method to get each member of the list.

Comment: I get an error User-defined type not defined for Dim myNameSpace As outlook.Namespace - ignore i didn't add the reference for outlook.

Comment: Now i get Run-Time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method for Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Comment: It seems both application objects are mixed in the code. Most probably you are trying to use Excel's Application object in the code.

Comment: i just copied what you provided above to test it.

Comment: This macro can be run from Outlook VBA without any modification. In Excel you need to create an Outlook Application instance and use it instead.

Comment: Oh i see can you advise what coding would do that please?

Comment: See [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications)

Comment: Anyone else able to provide an excel version of the above code instead of outlook vba please as i originally requested?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList` (returns `AddressEntries` collection) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getmemberoflist